# Method show(FragmentManager, String) is not applicable for show(FragmentManager, String) android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to get a dialog to warn the user that a screen should be viewed in landscape mode. I've got a dialog class and my activity calling the dialog, but it's complaining that show(FragmentManager, String) is not applicable for show(FragmentManager, String).

```
import my.application.dialogs.OrientationAlertDialog;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StationMapActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        OrientationAlertDialog dialog = new OrientationAlertDialog();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "String");
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_station_map);
    }
}
}
```

and my dialog class is:

```
import my.application.R;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class OrientationAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.landscape_dialog_alert)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.landscape_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       System.out.println("OK");
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.landscape_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       System.out.println("CANCEL");
                   }
               });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

I tweaked the code from the android dialog documentation, so I'm not sure where else to look for a solution.

Every way I've tried, the application just crashes when I press the button to come onto this activity.

Log cat doesn't print anything of use:

```
[2013-10-09 00:24:17 - my.application] ------------------------------
[2013-10-09 00:24:17 - my.application] Android Launch!
[2013-10-09 00:24:17 - my.application] adb is running normally.
[2013-10-09 00:24:17 - my.application] Performing my.application.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-10-09 00:24:24 - my.application] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-10-09 00:24:24 - my.application] Starting activity my.application.MainActivity on device 00194db94fb33f
[2013-10-09 00:24:25 - my.application] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=my.application/.MainActivity }
[2013-10-09 00:24:26 - my.application] Attempting to connect debugger to 'my.application' on port 8600
```

Comment: You probably need to reference FragmentManager from the support lib (i.e. the import should look like 'android.support.v4.app.') instead of the main SDK

Comment: What does the logcat print?

Comment: I made sure I had that import, in both classes and it's not made any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`, indicating that you are trying to use the Android Support package's backport of fragments. If that is the case, you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`, not `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I tried using this method and it just says the method is undefined.

Comment: @liloka: First, you need to decide whether you are going to use the backport or not. If you are, your activities that use fragments need to inherit from `FragmentActivity`, and then you will have `getSupportFragmentManager()`. If you are not going to use the backport, change your `DialogFragment` import to be `android.app.DialogFragment`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you :) I have no idea what the backport is though.